# HighCharts-Convert - Issue rendering heatmaps in .png format

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap, highcharts-convert

I use HighCharts.js 4.1.8 and heatmap.js 4.0.1.
Heatmaps are correctly generated and show as expected in the browser :
[screenshot 1 - heatmap in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA6R2.png)

However when we use the CLI phantomjs highcharts-convert utility to generate an image file, the image is not created as expected, it looks like the resolution is much smaller :
[Screenshot 2 : png generated using highcharts-convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJoZh.png)

I have tried various values of the -width and -scale parameter when running the highcharts-convert.js script, but have not been able to address the issue.
Can you help ?

Comment: Please show one example of yours "various values of the -width and -scale parameter when running the highcharts-convert.js script"

Comment: -scale 2, -scale 3 did not seem to change anything. Low values of width (<500) make things worse as resolution is lost. Large values of width (e.g. 2500) do not decisively change anything either. I have used these options exclusively (as, from documentation, -width takes precedence over -scale)

Comment: They official Highcharts documentation says that the server based on Phantom.js is **deprecated** (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/258). Try using the current version based on **Node.js**: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server

Comment: Thank you for these comments so far. I try to use the command-line rendering. It is unclear to me, from the documentation pages, if this really is deprecated : https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside . Could someone clarify for good ?

Answer (score 0):

After contacting HighCharts support : problem solved. The graph javascript did not contain a width value (in our application width is computed by the container, but there was no container when rendering from CLI).
The problem was solved after adding a width: value, as in :

```
   chart: {
                    type: 'heatmap',
                    renderTo: 'container',
                   backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
                   width: 1600
               },
```